# Haskore installation with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

When trying to install [Haskore](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskore), with `cabal` I get the following dependency conflict. (I have GHC 8.0.1)

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: base-4.9.0.0/installed-4.9... (dependency of haskore-0.2.0.8)
next goal: process (dependency of haskore-0.2.0.8:+splitbase)
rejecting: process-1.4.2.0/installed-1.4..., process-1.4.2.0, process-1.4.1.0,
process-1.4.0.0, process-1.3.0.0 (conflict: haskore-0.2.0.8:splitbase =>
process>=1.0 && <1.3)
rejecting: process-1.2.3.0, process-1.2.2.0, process-1.2.1.0 (conflict:
base==4.9.0.0/installed-4.9..., process => base>=4.4 && <4.9)
rejecting: process-1.2.0.0 (conflict: base==4.9.0.0/installed-4.9..., process
=> base>=4.4 && <4.8)
rejecting: process-1.1.0.2 (conflict: text =>
deepseq==1.4.2.0/installed-1.4..., process => deepseq>=1.1 && <1.4)
trying: process-1.1.0.1
next goal: directory (dependency of process-1.1.0.1)
rejecting: directory-1.2.6.2/installed-1.2..., directory-1.2.7.0,
directory-1.2.6.3, directory-1.2.6.2, directory-1.2.5.1, directory-1.2.5.0,
directory-1.2.4.0, directory-1.2.3.1, directory-1.2.3.0, directory-1.2.2.1,
directory-1.2.2.0, directory-1.2.1.0, directory-1.2.0.1, directory-1.2.0.0
(conflict: process => directory>=1.0 && <1.2)
rejecting: directory-1.1.0.2 (conflict: base==4.9.0.0/installed-4.9...,
directory => base>=4.4 && <4.6)
rejecting: directory-1.1.0.1 (conflict: base==4.9.0.0/installed-4.9...,
directory => base>=4.2 && <4.5)
rejecting: directory-1.1.0.0, directory-1.0.1.2 (conflict:
base==4.9.0.0/installed-4.9..., directory => base>=4.2 && <4.4)
rejecting: directory-1.0.1.1, directory-1.0.1.0 (conflict:
base==4.9.0.0/installed-4.9..., directory => base>=4.1 && <4.3)
rejecting: directory-1.0.0.3, directory-1.0.0.0 (conflict:
base==4.9.0.0/installed-4.9..., directory => base<4.3)
rejecting: directory-1.2.6.1 (conflict: process => directory>=1.0 && <1.2)
Backjump limit reached (currently 2000, change with --max-backjumps or try to
run with --reorder-goals).
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You could possibly try to install it with stack instead of cabal.

Comment: @Chris That wouldn't help at all, as [Haskore is not in any Stackage snapshot](https://www.stackage.org/package/haskore). Stack can be useful in many situations, but it is no silver bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `haskore` depends on a version of `process` that is not compatible with GHC 8.

Try

```
cabal install haskore --allow-newer=process
```